# How does one set a css class on a div returned from react's render()

Tags: css, reactjs

React seems to be removing the css class I want to set on the div returned from render. It even happens if I nest another div inside the first, and set the class on the enclosed div.

> var NightComponent = React.createClass({   render: function() {
>       return  
>               test
>               ;   } });

How do I do this in react?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`class` is not used to designate classes in React. You need to use `className`, as noted in the [React docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html).

> **Note:**
>   Since JSX is JavaScript, identifiers such as class and for are discouraged as XML attribute names. Instead, React DOM components expect DOM property names like `className` and `htmlFor`, respectively.

Comment: Thought I'd tried that, but I must have done something else wrong. You are correct. Thanks!

Comment: If this answers your question, please consider accepting this answer as the correct one.